# Not able to find ToggleButton in CollectionViewGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to find a `ToggleButton` associated in my CollectionViewGroup, my xaml structure is the following:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Matches}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchNation" />
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchLeague" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How you can see I've a `CollectionViewGroup` that filter the `ObservableCollection` binded `Matches` for `Nation` and `League`.

For this I've declared a `ListView` that have two `GroupStyle`, one that filter for `Country` and another for `League`, in this piece of code I add only the second GroupStyle (that contains the ToggleButton):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
    <!-- this is the second group style -->
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
         <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#4F4F4F">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <DockPanel Height="16.5">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="11.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

                                            <ToggleButton Checked="{Binding IsFavourite}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

So, how you can see in the second group style (`Nation -> League`) I've a ToggleButton.

Now the GroupStyle will be repeated based on the items available in the `ObservableCollection`, so for example:

```
|England
    |Premier League
     1. item  
     2. item 
     3. item 
|Afghanistan
     |Afghan Premier League
     1. item 
     2. item
```

this is the organization, now imagine that for `Premier League` of `England` and for `Afghan Premier League` of `Afghanistan` there is a `ToggleButton` that I've inserted on the right, I need to get all the `ToggleButtons` of each `Group` available on the list. I tried this:

```
var playingListSource = (ListCollectionView).Playing.Items.SourceCollection;

foreach (var gp in playingListSource.Groups)
{
       var rootGroup = (CollectionViewGroup)gp; //Convert the nested group
       var parentGroup = rootGroup.Items;
}
```

Essentially I extract the Group of the list and tried to find the ToggleButton on the nester group, but I cannot find it. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, things will be a lot easier if we name the `ToggleButton` so that we can later use the [`ControlTemplate.FindName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) method. So here's the `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="PART_ToggleButton"
              Checked="{Binding IsFavourite}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

What we need now is to get our hands on the templated container (a `GroupItem` control). For that we can use the [`ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Knowing that here's a piece of code that should retrieve the `ToggleButton` in question:

```
//we assume listView is a reference to the ListView
var playingListSource = (ListCollectionView)listView.ItemsSource;
//first we iterate over the top-level groups
foreach (CollectionViewGroup nationGroup in playingListSource.Groups)
{
    //second-level groups are items of their parents
    foreach (CollectionViewGroup leagueGroup in nationGroup.Items)
    {
        //first we retrieve the GroupItem control associated with current second-level group
        var container = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(leagueGroup) as GroupItem;
        //then we find the named ToggleButton inside the template
        var toggleButton = container.Template.FindName("PART_ToggleButton", container) as ToggleButton;
        //at this point we have a reference to the ToggleButton
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your code but I've a problem, the variable `toggleButton` is valorized with a `null` value. This is an image of the content of the property `Template` where you call the method `FindName`: http://imgur.com/a/EqY6k

Comment: Can you confirm that: **a)** you've assigned a name with `x:Name="PART_ToggleButton"` to the control inside the template, **b)** you're calling `FindName` with the exact same name mentioned in _a)_ ("PART_ToggleButton" is just an example, you can change it, but it must be the same in both places), and **c)** the control to which the name was assigned **is** in fact a `ToggleButton` (or derives from it)?

Comment: I finally found the problem. So I tried your code putting the `ToggleButton` in the `Template` and working well, in the first attemp it doesn't working 'cause I've overwritten the ToggleButton with my own style. So in the `Template` I've a `UserControl` with the `ToggleButton` inside, for more details, I've created a paste: http://pastebin.com/CXybKUFn I also add some comments to explain better the situation.

Comment: Since the answer I've provided addresses the question you posed I'll leave it as it is. As for your concerns, [here's a paste](http://pastebin.com/AFVV0wNp) that should get you going